# Jquery Mobile: Cloned row being added multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jsfiddle:

I am creating a mobile form that allows the user to add another row of inputs as needed.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="d" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
                <h4>Resident Birthday Cards</h4>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <table id="bcard_table">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:30%;">DATE</th>
                            <th style="width:40%;">NAME</th>
                            <th style="width:30%;">APT</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="bcard_entry">
                            <td><input type="date" name="bcards_date[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="bcards_name[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="bcards_apt[]" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p><a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" id="btnBCard">Add Another</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
        $(document).off('click', '#btnBCard').on('click', '#btnBCard',function(e) {
            $('.bcard_entry').clone().appendTo('#bcard_table');
        }); 
    });
```

I see what the problem is -- since I am cloing everything in class bcard_entry, it appends one copy the first time (but now there are two of that class). The second time will clone BOTH existing rows and append them and so on and so on.

Now I know what the problem is BUT I don't know how to avoid it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Any guidance and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an ID on the row you want to clone, and refer to it by ID (make sure to remove the ID in the cloned copy).

Or you could clone only the first row.  In JS that would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('bcard_table').appendChild(document.querySelector('.bcard_entry').cloneNode(true));
```

You'll probably want to clear the values and update the field names, too.

Alternatively, you could use templating.  There are some nice tools you could use, like Mustache (or create your own).

Comment: How would I remove the ID?

Comment: $('#bcard_entry').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#bcard_table'); --DUH!

Comment: You could remove the ID by using `Element.removeAttribute()` - so `newRow.removeAttribute('id')`